# Why is my Micronaut Controller bean not handled during tests

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I am trying to use micronaut from Kotlin. I have this:

```
package me.test

import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces

@Controller("/hello")
class Controller() {
    @Get("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    fun ping(): String {
        return "hello world"
    }
}
```

```
package me.test

import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut

object Application {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        Micronaut.build()
                .packages("me.test")
                .mainClass(Application.javaClass)
                .start()
    }
}
```

I wrote the following controller test:

```
package me.test

import io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest(application = Application::class)
class ControllerTest {

    @Inject
    @field:Client("/")
    private lateinit var client: RxHttpClient

    @Test
    fun `should server ping with a pong`() {
        val result = client.toBlocking().retrieve("/hello")
        println(result)
    }
}
```

but the test fails with a `HttpClientResponseException: Page Not Found`.

I have debugged this and from what I can tell, during the test, in `DefaultBeanContext.getBeanDefinitions` it doesn't find any beans for the `@Controller` qualifier. When I start the application using my `Application` class, I can see that it finds the `Controller` and makes the route available.

This is pretty much the Hello World for Micronaut, I am not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: How do you run your test? If you use IntelliJ - IntelliJ’s compiler does not support Kapt (annotation processing) - so you need run `gradle build` before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is purely IDE related. I have Intellij set up to use Annotation Processors, to delegate builds to Gradle and to use the Gradle Test Runner. However, you also need to delete any existing test configurations and then the problem goes away.

Comment: "you also need to delete any existing test configurations and then the problem goes away" - That part isn't necessarily true.  You can leave existing test configurations in place.  If you have annotation processors enabled in the IDE it doesn't matter if the test config is delegating to Gradle or not.